# long page height and background repeat issue

Tags: html, css, firefox, background, background-image

some pages on my website goes long height with comment !

in firefox and the end of the page  background was not show !!

here is my URL ,

http://kheiliii.com/blogs/%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8%E2%80%8C%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%D9%85%D9%86%D8%AA%D8%B4%D8%B1-%D8%B4%D8%AF%D9%87.html

how could I fix it ?
is it a firefox bug ?
thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jus give `background:fixed` in the body so that it wont scroll with page...

Comment: My Pleasure... Al d best... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
just keep your data in a <div> tag just apply overflow property to it as shown below

.[className]{
overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:hidden;
}

than all will be fine
```

Comment: could you please guide me witch class is over flow in my page ? it's seems no div goes over flow ...

Comment: just give an min-height for a div and if the content exceeds the given height than the div will overflow at that movement the above code will be helpfull